# Updating Node.js in Dockerfile breaks dependencies installation

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, dockerfile

I update Node.js base image in my Dockerfile from **12.14.1** to **16.14.2** and I’m not able to build an image with my Dockerfile anymore.

I’m not using any deprecated/removed dependencies.

I’m using the base images from a local Nexus repository. The old one was built with **node:12.14.1-alpine** and the new one is built with **node:16.14.2-alpine** with some commands inside.

Here is the original Dockerfile:

```
FROM local-nexus/node-12.14.1
WORKDIR /opt/microservice
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g sails @vue/cli@4.4.6
RUN (cd frontend && npm install && npm run deploy)

# AFTER UPDATE to NODE 16.14.2, BUILD IMAGE FAILES AT LINE ABOVE. SO THE LINES BELLOW ARE NOT TOO IMPORTANT AT THIS STAGE.

RUN (cd backend && npm install && npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org fix)
RUN mkdir -p /tar
RUN cd backend && tar -czvf /tar/my-app.tar.gz .

EXPOSE 443 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Again, the only change here was switching the first line to:

> FROM local-nexus/node-16.14.2

Now, when I try to build the image with

> docker build -t myimage/myapp

it fails complaining about **vue-cli-service** which is among the devdependencies in package.json:

```
sh: vue-cli-service: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c (cd frontend && npm install && npm run deploy)' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here is the full output when building the image

```
my-VirtualBox:~/ideaprojects/my-app$ docker build -t ali/app .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   3.68GB
Step 1/10 : FROM frk-docker-registry.spirentcom.com:5001/spirent/vsa-base-container:node-16.14.2
 ---> 6ac4e9781a5b
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /opt/microservice
 ---> Running in 41b27c84edae
Removing intermediate container 41b27c84edae
 ---> 44939f239c13
Step 3/10 : COPY . .
 ---> cba32c296e48
Step 4/10 : RUN npm install -g sails @vue/cli@4.4.6
 ---> Running in 946c624b895b
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead

added 1133 packages, and audited 1134 packages in 53s

63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

18 vulnerabilities (1 low, 9 moderate, 8 high)

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.5.0 -> 8.5.5
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.5>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.5.5` to update!
npm notice 
Removing intermediate container 946c624b895b
 ---> 938881f9f599
Step 5/10 : RUN (cd frontend && npm install && npm run deploy)
 ---> Running in 0157b7dbf624

up to date, audited 186 packages in 8s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

11 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 6 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

> vsa-user-interface@3.9.5 deploy
> echo 'export default { enabled: false }' > ./src/api/mocks/setting.js && vue-cli-service build && cp -R dist/* ../backend/assets && echo 'export default { enabled: true }' > ./src/api/mocks/setting.js

sh: vue-cli-service: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c (cd frontend && npm install && npm run deploy)' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

And here is the package.json file in my project, in “frontend” folder:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "2.2.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "deploy": "echo 'export default { enabled: false }' > ./src/api/mocks/setting.js && vue-cli-service build && cp -R dist/* ../backend/assets && echo 'export default { enabled: true }' > ./src/api/mocks/setting.js",
    "deploy-win": "echo export default { enabled: false }> ./src/api/mocks/setting.js && vue-cli-service build && xcopy \"dist\\*\" \"..\\backend\\assets\" /s /e && echo export default { enabled: true }> ./src/api/mocks/setting.js",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "mathjs": "^9.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "sails.io.js": "^1.2.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-chartist": "2.1.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-meta": "1.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.32",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "yaml": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^6.5.95",
    "@mdi/js": "^4.9.95",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "wait-for-expect": "^3.0.2",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "~1.26.8",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Something's not letting some dependencies get installed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like not all dependencies got installed; you should show the output before `sh: vue-cli-service: not found` too. (If you can't see the output, run the build with the `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain` envvar set.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Going to add it.

Comment: Just updated the question with the full output.

Comment: Is `NODE_ENV` set to `production`? If so your dev dependencies will be skipped. Try removing all containers too.

Comment: Hmmm...I see what you mean. The thing is there was no complain before updating Node.js with the same `package.json` and `NODE_ENV` set to `production`. I should go deeper and see how `@vue/cli-service` was getting installed. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You can do `npm install -- production=false` to install dev dependencies while `NODE_ENV=production`.

Comment: Thanks @morganney! It turned out that `NODE_ENV` was set to `production` in the base image I used in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom base image I used in `Dockerfile` which is built with `node:16.14.2-alpine` and getting pulled from a private repository had `NODE_ENV` set to `production` which was not letting `devdependencies` getting installed.

I had a few workarounds:

1. `npm install --production=false`
2. Overriding `NODE_ENV` in the `Dockerfile`
3. Not setting `NODE_ENV` to production in the base image
4. Move the devDepndencies to dependencies in package.json

Since this Dockerfile was not really a production thing and was used for testing, I created a second custom base image that didn't have `NODE_ENV` set to `production` and used it as the base image in Dockerfile.

Thanks for all the helpful comments above!